# How do I open a ruby gem in Sublime on Windows 7 using command prompt?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, windows, rubygems

I have added Sublime's directory to the system path, so when I enter "`subl`" in comman promot it opens the Sublime, that's fine. But,
When I tried to open a ruby gem, I remembered the command used in Linux etc which is "`bundle open xyz`", I entered this command to Windows 7's command prompt it gave me an error as "***To open a bundled gem, set $EDITOR or $BUNDLER_EDITOR***".
I assumed that I must mention that i wanna open it through sublime, so I edited the command as "`subl bundle open sass`", but it ***opened a new file named ''bundle open sass''*** in sublime (not the sass gem).
Does anyone know how to open a ruby gem in sublime or whatever editor from command prompt in Windows?
Thank You!

**Edit:** After [pdobb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171183/pdobb)'s [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30481695/1954881) I created a variable named EDITOR in my environment variables, and set its value to subl (I assumed that the path is not needed along the "subl" because its path is already set in the path variable), but now its showing the error as "Could not locate gemfile", but when I list my gems its there.

Here is the snapshot of how I set the EDITOR variable.
[image: EDITOR variable in system environment variables.]

Answer (score 2):

The command is `bundle open xyz`, as you've said. The editor you want to use is set in the `$EDITOR` or `$BUNDLER_EDITOR` environment variable. In effect, bundler checks this environment variable for what editor to open the gem in. So, you just need to set the environment variable `$EDITOR` to `subl`. This is done in the same place as where you set your `$PATH` environment variable. See [here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) for a guide.

Comment: I created a variable named EDITOR and set its value to subl, but it didn't work, now its saying "could not locate Gemfile",but when I list gems its there in the list.

Answer (score 0):

you can go to the directory where the gem is installed and open the directory with your editor.

For example,

If the ruby gems are installed on .rvm/ruby-2.1.0/gems/. Let's say, you want to open 'capybara' gem. then open the .rvm/ruby-2.1.0/gems/capybara in your editor